# Profiling each thread in a multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, winapi, mfc, profiling

Is there any way to find out the actual time spent by a thread inside the CPU using MFC/Win32? By actual time, I mean I don't want to count the time the thread spent in states other than "Running". I tried GetThreadTimes() method in Win32 SDK but couldn't get the proper values. I want to do this because I want to check effect of setting the ThreadPriority on its scheduling i.e. how much of a difference does it make if I set the thread priority to THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL instead of THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL?

Here is the actual code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxmt.h>
#include <time.h>



bool bStop = false;
long k1 = 0;
long k2 = 0;



UINT run1(LPVOID param)
{
    while(!bStop)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            ++k1;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


UINT run2(LPVOID param)
{
    while(!bStop)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            ++k2;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    CWinThread* pThread1 =  AfxBeginThread(&run1, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
    CWinThread* pThread2 =  AfxBeginThread(&run2, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL );

    Sleep(3 * 1000);

    bStop = TRUE;

    FILETIME f1,f2,f3,f4;
    GetThreadTimes(*pThread1, &f1,&f2,&f3,&f4);
    CTime t1(f4);



    std::cout<<"K1="<<k1<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"K2="<<k2<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Thread1 Time="<<t1.GetSecond()<<"sec\n";
    std::cout<<"Exit\n";
}
```

Comment: GetThreadTimes() is the way to do this, it'd help if you showed how you are calling it and what you mean by not getting proper values.

Comment: What is in the loop of your threads? This may impact the execution time reported. Also, what does your time convert code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetThreadTimes() will give you the correct values. The problem is it gives it in FILETIME structure. You will have to convert FILETIME structure into a time that is easy to display to a user. You can do it with API [FileTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724280(VS.85).aspx) :

```
SYSTEMTIME stUTC;        
FileTimeToSystemTime(&f4, &stUTC);
std::cout<<"Thread1: Hour:"<<stUTC.wHour<<" Min:"<<stUTC.wMinute<<" Sec:"<<stUTC.wSecond<<" millSec:"<<stUTC.wMilliseconds<<std::endl;
```

In my machine the output was : `Thread1: Hour:0 Min:0 Sec:3 millSec:0`

Please ignore the year\day details as FILETIME Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

Don't forget to add kernerl time and user time to get the total time.